# Putting one line of an align environment in a different font size

Tags: align, fontsize

I have to format a .tex file following certain guidelines. I have an equation which has one line which is very big, and the only way I see of making it fit into the page (other than substantial rewriting or really messy notation) is to put it in a smaller font size. The rest of the equation is fine, so I would like to keep that in normal size, if possible. Thus, I would like to do something like:

```
\begin{align*}
line 1\\
line 2\\
{\small huge line}\\
line 4
\end{align*}
```

Is this possible? And what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: don't do this!!:)  apart from it not looking nice it will be hard to do this while maintaining your alignment (your test file shows a misleading easy but unrealistic case as there are no `&` alignment points, which means `align` would nit be used in practice)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The line starts with `=&\ (...)`, so the alignment is not a problem. I agree it's not optimal, and I try to avoid resizing whenever possible, but in this case I really don't see any other solution.

Comment: If you really need `=&`, it should be `={}&`, which avoids the wrong “backslash space”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the  medium size commands from `nccmath` : `\medmath, \medop, \medint, \mfrac`, &c., which reduces the size to about 80 % of `\displaystyle`:

```
\begin{align*}
line 1\\
line 2\\
\medmath{huge line}\\
line 4
\end{align*}
```

Note `\medmath` cannot include the alignment markers`&`.

However, the result will usually be nicer if you break the longer lines with one of the `split`, `aligned` or `multlined` environments.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! I would have preferred to split the line - it's what I do usually when confronted with this kind of problems - but unfortunately in this case it was not possible.